# Post Json Data using volly library to wcf rest service

Tags: c#, android, json, wcf, rest

I am migrating from asynctask to volley.In my application I want json data from my WCF REST service.My code is as below

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(error.networkResponse != null && error.networkResponse.data != null){
                        VolleyError error2 = new VolleyError(new String(error.networkResponse.data));
                        error = error;
                    }
                    Log.d("ERROR", "error => " + error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params1 = new HashMap<>();
            params1.put("userid", "123");
            params1.put("password", "123");
            return params1;
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    } ;
```

But I am getting error 'HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name' from WCF service...

Comment: "The request has an invalid header name" I think the server dose not expect `application/json` maybe it wants `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or other thing so try not sending any header.

Comment: Use the google chrome network analyzer or fiddler to see the http message. This may help you to see what is going wrong.

Comment: sir mmlooloo, I have tried both but still get error 400...

Comment: sir rafa,i have seen in fiddler and restclient..both give me json as i expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late reply.There is some problem with WCF Rest service it will give backslash encoded JSon so volley didnt got JSON content type

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
        url, params,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
               JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
               JSONObject uniObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("yourObjectName");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {

    /**
     * Passing some request headers
     * */
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }

};
```

Comment: thanks for your response sir.I have tried this but in response i got error that java.lang.String could not converted into java.lang.jsonobject.means i got response only in string thats why i chose stringrequest...

Comment: you need to parse string to JSON

Comment: No Response sir..same error as usual..java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: yourObject.toString();

Comment: I put break point to onresponse method...but it does not go there

Comment: it will not go there. call method from onResponse() and put break point on it.

Comment: i have put showempname(String empid) method in onResponse but still not go there